# How to find a x,y coordinates in depth image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, open3d

i am using Open3d a OpenCV to make a depth image from point cloud, find circles in depth image a delete point in original point cloud.

I first make point cloud from numpy array and visualize it with and capture depth image and save image as .png .I also save interior and exterior camera  parameters.

after that i find the circles in depth image with Hough transform. From that i get center pixel(u,v) and radius of the circle.

now i want to delete all points inside this circles in orginal point cloud. So i need to know x,y of point cloud where circles was found.

so i use this,

x = (u - cx) * z / fx

y = (v - cy) * z / fy

where x,y are point cloud coordinates u,v are pixel coordinates cx,cy,fx,fy are interior orientation parameters.
but i am not getting right values.

My question is how to find all points inside circles and delete them or is there smarter waz to do it?

```
xyz = np.array([points[:, 0], points[:, 1], points[:, 2]]).T

XYZ = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
XYZ.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(xyz)
visZ = o3d.visualization.Visualizer()
visZ.create_window(width=1980, height=1080, left=5,top=5)
visZ.add_geometry(XYZ)
view_control = visZ.get_view_control()
camera_parameters = view_control.convert_to_pinhole_camera_parameters()
#print("# Initial camera parameters\n{}\n{}".format(camera_parameters.extrinsic, camera_parameters.intrinsic.intrinsic_matrix))
intri = camera_parameters.intrinsic.intrinsic_matrix
extri = camera_parameters.extrinsic
visZ.run()
image1 = visZ.capture_depth_float_buffer()
photo_save = np.asarray(image1)
plt.imsave("testov.png", \
           np.asarray(photo_save), dpi=1)
plt.imshow(np.asarray(photo_save))
plt.close()
plt.show()
visZ.destroy_window()
```

```
img = cv2.imread('testov.png',0)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1.5,20,
                           param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=50)
print(circles)

circles = np.around(circles)
for i in circles[0,:]:
   # draw the outer circle
   cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
   # draw the center of the circle
   cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)


cv2.imshow('detected circles',cimg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

```
image = Image.open('testov.png')
size = w,h = image.size
data =image.load()
for u in range(w):
   for v in range(h):
       x = (data[u,0] - intri[0,2]) * data[u,3] / intri[0,0]
       y = (data[v,1] - intri[1,2]) * data[u,3] / intri[1,1]
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible code :)

Comment: Hi, i edited my guestion with my lateset attempt. I know it is not right, but i am trying everything. :)